# Assigning a float value to variable

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

I want to store 1.222 in the variable a.But when i print it is showing me 1.222000 which

means that the variable a is stored as 1.222000.But i want to store the value as 1.222 in

a. and also i want only 1.22 to be copied to b when assign a=b. Please help me to

understand how to do it.

```
int main()
{
    float a=1.222,b;
    b=a;//(but b=1.22 and not b=1.222) how to cut the last number 2
    printf("%f\t%f",a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But these are the same! It's a printing issue, not storage issue.

Comment: Actually, the value is probably *not* stored as `1.222000` due to limited floating-point accuracy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't simply tell a float to lose some digits of precision during an assignment, you'll have to do some type casting to get the intended result. For instance, to preserve only 2 digits of precision:

```
int main()
{
    float a=1.222,b;
    b= ((long)(a * 100)) / 100.0;
    printf("%f\t%f",a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: :Thanks for making me to understand.

Comment: @Angus: You can only *approximate* storing 2 decimal digits in a `float` object (unless your implementation uses decimal floating-point, which is unlikely). For example, the actual value stored in `b` is probably `1.2200000286102294921875`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily change the storage value, as that's the amount of allocated memory, and that's determined by the data type and system. To print two decimal places, use

```
printf("%.2f, %.2f", a, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change out it is stored and your issue has nothing to do with how it is stored. You have a *printing* issue.

If you want to remove the extra zeroes, change `%f` to `%g`. But this will print `1.222`.

If you want to print `1.22` and not `1.222` then change it to `%.2f` instead of `%f`.

Comment: :Thanks for explaining.How do i store b=a where 1.22 of a gets stored and not 1.222 which is actual a's value.

Comment: @Beata: 1.22 is a repeating number.

Comment: @sidyll:b=((int)(a*100)/100.0)... a*100 =122.2/100.0 ... how that last 2 got eliminated.why do we typecast the result we got to int.

Comment: @Beata: thanks, indeed the last 100 should be 100.0, my bad. The trick is exactly in the cast. When you cast an floating point number to an int, it gets truncated (decimal part eliminated). So 1.222 x 100 gives 122.2, then we cast into an int and it becomes 122. Finally, dividing by 100.0 will promote it to an floating point again and result in 1.22. `b=((int)a*100)/100.0`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to round the number itself:

```
b=round(100*a)/100;
```